# Php - Upload 5 different files for database

Tags: php, file, upload

[This is the idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kBLC.jpg)
I am making a CRUD system, and I am stuck a little bit.
So I've succeded in adding the photo for employees, but I also need to be able to post ID, Tax Card, Contract, Employment record book all at the same page but with different inputs.
Here is the picture of the Profile Pic. Input.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmBgP.jpg)

```
<tr>
           <td><label class="control-label">Profile Picture</label></td>
           <td><input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image" `accept="image/*" />`
      </td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
           <td colspan="2">
           <button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-default">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Save
           </button>
          </td>
       </tr>
PHP Code:


     $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
     $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
     $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];

        $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

        // valid image extensions
        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

        // rename uploading image
        $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

        // allow valid image file formats
        if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
            // Check file size '5MB'
            if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            }
        }
        else{
            $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
        }
    }
```

And this successfully gets the image file in the database.
Should I make next input field like this:

```
   <input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_taxCard" accept="image/*" />
```

How to approach the php code?
I am new to php, so don't be harsh please.Thank you in advance.

P.S My input field for the picture is this:

```
    <input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image" accept="image/*" />
```

Comment: I've never played with uploading more than one file at a time, but I would expect all the files to be available in the `$_FILES` global, keyed by the `name` attribute that you gave to the `input` element.  Have you tried just putting them all on there and seeing what is available in `$_FILES`?

Comment: You should try to name your fields as image1, image2, image3 etc. That way you can use a foreach loop and reduce code redundancy. I guess you are randomly renaming all the files, so there's no need to identify the image by it's name.

Comment: @h4r5h4 The uploaded file names are not important. It is important that they are assigned to the respective user. I can for example name "user_image", "user_taxcard", "user_contract" etc.

Comment: You can specify an array as `['user_image', 'user_taxcard', 'user_contract']`.
And use this array to iterate through the files. You will also name the html fields as above

Comment: I tryed some things but they aren't working....damn

Comment: http://prntscr.com/biv6l3 This is the idea